# Apple Script + Shell Script: Works in terminal, but not in Apple Script

Tags: shell, applescript

```
do shell script "cd '~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/';

    if [ -d 'rezcraft_bin' ]
        then
            mv 'bin' 'sanguine_bin';
            mv 'rezcraft_bin' 'bin';     
    fi
    exit"
```

why does that happen? when copied to terminal, everything works... =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use single quotes in a shell script, it doesn't perform variable expansion, so `~` is used verbatim. Change the first line to

```
do shell script "cd ~/Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/;
```

(i.e., don't single-quote the path) and your script should work.

Comment: still doesn't work. my guess is that now there is a problem with teh space in application support. cause in the terminal, you need to say "Application\ Support".... =\

Comment: Whoops, missed the space in the path. You basically need to escape the `\` that escapes the space. I updated my answer to demonstrate.